# Can someone explain to me why my div won't appear as a triangle?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to turn my empty div into a triangle but everything I've tried produces the same result, nothing. I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes can tell me what I'm missing.

```css
body {
  background-color: #0A3D75;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.shape {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid #E07D00; 
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0 solid transparent;
}

/*I've also tried this*/

.shape {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #E07D00;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100px 100px 0 0;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h1>Alex Wilbur</h1>
      <p>UI Designer/Front-end Developer - Graphic Artist - Indie Game Developer</p>
      <h2>Imagination brought to life</h2>
      <div class="shape"></div>
    </header>
  </body>
```

I have also tried changing the width and height of the body and header but that also did nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: The triangle is visible if you remove your comment and everything below it from your CSS.

Comment: You have width:0 and height:0. It's invisible!

Comment: The thing is I didn't write it like that in my editor. The css I have currently is just what is above the comment, I only put the comment and css below it in the snippet to show other things I have tried. With that being said even without the comment and everything below it it's still not showing up

Comment: I've tried changing the width and height too with no success

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```css
body {
  background-color: #0A3D75;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.shape {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li id="portfolio"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h1>Alex Wilbur</h1>
      <p>UI Designer/Front-end Developer - Graphic Artist - Indie Game Developer</p>
      <h2>Imagination brought to life</h2>
      <div class="shape"></div>
    </header>
  </body>
```

Comment: I've tried that too but it still won't show up when I put it in my editor. All my other css is working though